# как изменить тему в rainmeter через python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

[image: темы]
**текущую тему нужно поменять на test через python**
у rainmeter есть c#/c++ [api](https://docs.rainmeter.net/developers/)
Причём работать на устройствах с любым экраном.

Comment: оно не будет работать на разных мониторах

Comment: там есть api на c#/c/c++